# Excel SUM COUNTIFS from different tables and futureproofing

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I'm practising MS Excel skills. I have a workbook in which I want to analyses data from different tables.

Each worksheet contains a table with the information from the year. So in worksheet "2017" I have a table named "Table2017". I have this for each year (starting 2015).

After a some research, I finally found a way to count how many times something in a certain place happened.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table2018[Place];B3;Table2018[Activity];{"Paid";"Awarded"}))
+SUM(COUNTIFS(Table2017[Place];B3;Table2017[Activity];{"Paid";"Awarded"}))
+SUM(COUNTIFS(Table2016[Place];B3;Table2016[Activity];{"Paid";"Awarded"}))
+SUM(COUNTIFS(Table2015[Place];B3;Table2015[Activity];{"Paid";"Awarded"}))
```

This works perfectly. It will calculate how many times per place a paid service or an awarded (gifted/sponsored) service was delivered. In the B column, I have a list of places (hence the B3 reference), so after completing the formula, I can select the cell and enlarge/drag to copy it to the rest of the column and apply for every place.

However, the formula is really long and every year upon creating a new worksheet, I need to add a new part to the formula.

Is there a way to compact this? And ideally have the formula search for every table that has the relevant information (like: "Table20??" or "Table 20*"), go in and count the times my conditions are found?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have zero experience in VBA/VBS, so I'm hoping to realize this in a normal formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to make it more compact, but they will necessarily make the function more complicated, so it wont be any easy win. See for yourself:
you basically need to be able to cycle through the years inside formula without creating custom formulas. One way to do this is to use ROW inside INDIRECT function. This way you can replace multiple

```
Table2015[Place]
```

with one array function containing

```
INDIRECT("Table"&ROW($A$2015:$A$2018)&"[Place]")
```

as it is an array function it will essentially cycle through the cells in the ROW function creating Table2015[Place], Table2016[Place], Table2017[Place] and Table2018[Place]. Your whole formula would look something like this

```
 =SUM(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table"&ROW($A$2015:$A$2018)&"[Place]");B3;INDIRECT("Table"&ROW($A$2015:$A$2018)&"[Activity]");{"Paid";"Awarded"}))
```

and it must be entered using ctrl+shift+enter (you will see {} brackets around the function). This should work to make the function smaller and you will need only to change the cell reference each year instead of adding another sum, but the question is if the separate sums are not easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely smaller. It's still not very complicated to read. Curious though what the $A does in $A$year

Comment: it refers to a cell in order to get the row number, so I pointed it to A2015 as the column doesnt really matter. I guess you could use ROW(2015:2018) or something like that, but I didnt really test that... Interesting - I alway put there automatically a cell, not really thinking about it. I did a small test and it really seems to be working just as ROW(2015:2018) which would be more easily readable.

Comment: I was thinking this over again. Since this formula comes back in several cells (for each place), and even though it's not a big issue to update one cell each year and drag it down to copy... What if I make a separate table that simply includes the names of all tables that should be included? So if I add a row in that table with 2019 next year (after creating it), the formulas will automatically be updated everywhere?
Do I replace ROW(2015:2018) with ROW(TableYearsToInclude[Years]) ?

Comment: without the ROW - you dont want ROW of the table contents, you want the table contents. I created table TableYears with column Years and then this works in the formula INDIRECT("Table"&TableYears[Years]&"[Place]"). Then all you need to do is create a new Table20xx and add the new value int otable TableYears and you wont have to touch the formula at all